# Identify a deployed SSAS HOLAP Database (insert a version number in the SSAS Project)

Tags: ssas

I can't see which version of my SSAS project is deployed on the server.

I mean, with a .Net C# or VB.Net project you can set the "version number" in the project's Assembly Information properties, so you can look at any .dll or .exe file deployed and you can relate it to a specific source version.

How can I do the same with a SSAS project? How can I look at a project deployed into a SQL SSAS server (i.ie, a SSAS database) and know for sure which source version has been used?

Answer (score 1):

Could you add a calculated measure to the cube that is hardcoded to be the version?